# How to run my Countdown Timer in Service in Latest API Level?

Tags: android, android-studio, service, countdowntimer, android-api-levels

As we know latest API level in android version don't allow long background task in application. So, how can I run my 12 Hours countdown Timer in background because I have to do some task on Timer finish. So How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right way to schedule tasks based on time or certain constraints (e.g when device is idle, or when it is charging etc) is by using `WorkManager`. Take a look at it: 
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/

Specifically, for recurring tasks, have a look at this section:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics#recurring

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Service and a BroadcastReceiver

here the link to do this :

https://deepshikhapuri.wordpress.com/2016/11/07/android-countdown-timer-run-in-background/